# All data not inserted of text area field

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a form to insert teacher information to database.Form submit process almost ok , but problem is one text area's all data does not insert into database. Some data now inserted but not all data. such as , if I insert:

"It is a professional teacher to be in 11 years finger guidance history. I have completed the Master's. My hobbies are to a wide range of sports from poetry. Personality is gentle serious basically, Minuki as early as possible the character of the students, you can go to pull steadily to match it, for example, paced students slowly, which corresponds on a case-by-case basis. There is also a place like children, and has been revered as the older sister intimate students from many."

but data insert only

"It is a professional teacher to be in 11 years finger guidance history. I have completed the Master's. My hobbies are to a wide range of sports from poetry. Personality is gentle serious basically, Minuki as early as possible the character of the students, you can go to pull steadily to match it, for example, paced students slowly, which corresponds on a case-by-case basis."

Some data is missing in database. In database for this field column name is 'description', and length of this column is 500.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are limiting the characters to be entered in the database so how do you expect MySQL to accept more? Just use `text` type without any character limit, I assume that you are using PHPMyAdmin so alter the table and remove `500` from `length/values` column.

Steps ----------

- Select your table.
- Select Structure Tab Here

[image]

- Now you'll get a list of columns with their type, length etc so here what you'll get a column with controls name **Action**, in that column click on **Change** option for your **description** column

[image]

And now get rid of 500 here

[image]

```
                            -----^-----
    //Remove 500 from here, that limits the characters to your database
```

Comment: +1 for at least you provided an answer, I dislike whose just down voting...

Comment: @Akam Thank you, and you can upvote the question too if you think that downvoting this was not fair :)